# Ensure no threads are waiting on a Critical Section before destroying it

Tags: c, winapi, critical-section

I have an issue in my use of critical sections.  My app has a large number of threads, say 60, which all need access to a global resource.  I therefore protect that resource with a critical section.  This works perfectly during operation, however when my application shuts down, I trigger the threads to quit, and then destroy the critical section.

The problem comes if some of those threads are waiting on the critical section at exit time, and thus are blocked from quitting themselves.

I've written a wrapper around the windows CriticalSection calls that has an 'Initialised' flag, which I set to true when the crit is created, and set to false when I'm about to leave the crit (both cases are set when inside the crit).  This flag is checked before the 'enter crit' wrapper function tries entering the crit, bypassing the request if the flag is false.  The flag is also checked the moment any thread successfully enters the crit, making it immediately leave the crit if it's false.

What I to do prior to deleting the crit is set the flag to false, then wait for any waiting threads to: be allowed into the crit; see the Initialised flag is false; then leave the crit (which should be a pretty quick operating for each thread).

I check the number of threads waiting for access to the crit by checking the LockCount inside the CRITICAL_SECTION struct, and waiting until it hits 0 (in XP, that's `LockCount - (RecursionCount-1)`; in 2003 server and above, the lock count is `((-1) - (LockCount)) >> 2`), before I then destroy the critical section.

This *should* be sufficient, however I'm finding that the LockCount reaches 0 when there's still one thread (always just one thread, never more) waiting to enter the crit, meaning if I delete the crit at that point, the other thread subsequently wakes up from waiting on the crit, and causes a crash as the CRITICAL_SECTION object has by that time been destroyed.

If I keep my own internal lock count of threads waiting for access, I have the correct count; however this isn't ideal as I have to increment this count outside of the crit, meaning that value isn't protected and therefore can't be entirely relied upon at any one time.

Does anyone know why the LockCount in the CRITICAL_SECTION struct would be out by 1?  If I use my own lock count, then check the CRITICAL_SECTION's lock count *after* that last thread has exited (and before I destroy the crit), it's still 0...

Or, is there a better way for me to protect the global resource in my app with that many threads, other than a critical section?

This is my wrapper struct:

```
typedef struct MY_CRIT {
    BOOL Initialised;
    CRITICAL_SECTION Crit;
    int MyLockCount;
}
```

Here's my Crit init function:

```
BOOL InitCrit( MY_CRIT *pCrit )
{
    if (pCrit)
    {
        InitializeCriticalSection( &pCrit->Crit );          
        pCrit->Initialised = TRUE;
        pCrit->MyLockCount = 0;
        return TRUE;
    }
    // else invalid pointer
    else    
        return FALSE;
}
```

This is my enter crit wrapper function:

```
BOOL EnterCrit( MY_CRIT *pCrit )
{
    // if pointer valid, and the crit is initialised
    if (pCrit && pCrit->Initialised)
    {
        pCrit->MyLockCount++;
        EnterCriticalSection( &pCrit->Crit );
        pCrit->MyLockCount--;

        // if still initialised
        if (pCrit->Initialised)
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
        // else someone's trying to close this crit - jump out now!
        else
        {
            LeaveCriticalSection( &pCrit->Crit );
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    else // crit pointer is null
        return FALSE;
}
```

And here's my FreeCrit wrapper function:

```
void FreeCrit( MY_CRIT *pCrit )
{
    LONG    WaitingCount = 0;

    if (pCrit && (pCrit->Initialised))
    {
        // set Initialised to FALSE to stop any more threads trying to get in from now on:
        EnterCriticalSection( &pCrit->Crit );
        pCrit->Initialised = FALSE;
        LeaveCriticalSection( &pCrit->Crit );

        // loop until all waiting threads have gained access and finished:
        do {
            EnterCriticalSection( &pCrit->Crit );

            // check if any threads are still waiting to enter:
            // Windows XP and below:
            if (IsWindowsXPOrBelow())
            {
                if ((pCrit->Crit.LockCount > 0) && ((pCrit->Crit.RecursionCount - 1) >= 0))
                    WaitingCount = pCrit->Crit.LockCount - (pCrit->Crit.RecursionCount - 1);
                else
                    WaitingCount = 0;
            }
            // Windows 2003 Server and above:
            else
            {
                WaitingCount = ((-1) - (pCrit->Crit.LockCount)) >> 2;
            }

                        // hack: if our own lock count is higher, use that:
            WaitingCount = max( WaitingCount, pCrit->MyLockCount );

            // if some threads are still waiting, leave the crit and sleep a bit, to give them a chance to enter & exit:
            if (WaitingCount > 0)
            {
                LeaveCriticalSection( &pCrit->Crit );
                // don't hog the processor:
                Sleep( 1 );
            }
            // when no other threads are waiting to enter, we can safely delete the crit (and leave the loop):
            else
            {
                DeleteCriticalSection( &pCrit->Crit );
            }
        } while (WaitingCount > 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I should note: The LeaveCrit() wrapper function simply checks the pointer is valid, then leaves the crit (no point checking `Initialised` flag as we want to leave the crit regardless). Also, in my actual implementation I have a timeout in the CritFree loop that jumps out after 10 seconds, to avoid infinite looping - better to crash than be stuck looping forever.

Comment: The CRITICAL_SECTION's inner working is, as you mentioned, OS version-specific. Therefore you shouldn't rely on it, but rather maintain the number of waiting threads explicitly as a number. The access to that number can be protected with the very same CRITICAL_SECTION.

Comment: @Vlad: How can I protect the 'waiting thread' number with the same crit, if I have to wait to enter the crit before being able to increment the fact I'm waiting to enter it?...  I agree that I shouldn't rely on the inner workings though; it's just the lesser of two evils at present.

Comment: in any case, CRITICAL_SECTION _must not_ be locked for any significant amount of time. The whole idea of critical section is to mark a _short_, really _critical_ part of your algo, which needs exclusive access to resources. So waiting on it should not be a problem. If it however is a problem, just use another CRITICAL_SECTION for the amount (and check your code: it's perhaps using critical sections in a wrong way).

Comment: OK, what happens if you comment out all of the 'I trigger the threads to quit, and then destroy the critical section.' stuff, ie. just don't do it at all?

Comment: @Martin James: I end up with a memory leak on the crit, but otherwise it exits fine (i.e. all the threads close happily).

Comment: What reports the memory leak?  The OS should recycle the CS handle just fine when the OS terminates the service process.

Comment: Sorry, it's not shown in the code.  The "MY_CRIT" pointer is malloced inside the app, and usually freed after it's destroyed. Commenting out the destroy causes the leak.  There's also the handle leak for the actual CRITICAL_SECTION object, but yes that would be freed on app exit.  Not ideal though if I want to 'restart' an internal component of my app mid-runtime which has to free the crit...

Comment: @NickShaw - indeed, only useful upon app termination.  Component 'restarts' should not be necessary but, yes, of course there are rubbish components.. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are responsible to make sure that CS is not in use any longer before destroying it. Let us say that no other thread is currently trying to enter, but there is a chance that it is going to attempt very soon. Now you destroy the CS, what this concurrent thread is going to do? At its full pace it hits deleted critical section causing memory access violation?

The actual solution depends on your current app design, but if you are destroying threads, then you will perhaps want to flag your request to stop those threads, and then wait on theit handles to wait for their destruction. And then complete with deleting critical section when you are sure that threads are done.

Note that it is unsafe to rely on CS member values such as `.LockCount`, and having done things right way you will prehaps not even need thing like `IsWindowsXPOrBelow`. Critical section API suggest that you use `CRITICAL_SECTION` structure as "black box" leaving the internals to be implementation specific.

Comment: Thanks @Roman R. Whilst it's true that I'd *like* to treat the critical section struct as a black box, it lacks features that we require in our code, mainly for determining when a crit has been initialised, and making sure nothing's using it before it's deleted. We were implementing these features so often in individual codes, I wrote this wrapper to contain the features. So waiting on the threads quitting would need doing in each bit of code we use the crits in, which is all over the place. I wanted a single solution for all - maybe that's just not achievable I guess.

Comment: This is really the wrong way to go about it.  The correct approach is as Roman R suggests; signal your worker threads to stop, then wait for them to stop before destroying the critical section object.  If the threads are not under your control then you need to initialize/destroy the critical section in a more logical place (e.g. WinMain/DllMain).  Locking code is notoriously difficult to get right; best to leave it to the experts.

Comment: Thanks Luke.  It's entirely because is difficult to get right that I've had to add these wrappers, as some of our code is incredibly complex and interlinked.  But I know exactly what you're saying, and I do agree.  Think reorganising the thread creation/destruction methodology may be the best way to go.

Comment: The best thread creation/destruction methodology, by a huge margin, is to create them at app startup and never destroy them at all.  Signalling worker threads to stop, then waiting for them to stop, is a messy exercise that is often very difficult and best avoided if possible, (as you have found out).  Following the 'you must gracefully shut down threads and wait for them' philosophy is the reason for the thousands of 'How to stop my threads' and 'my app will not shut down' posts on SO and other blogs.